# Localization with layered costmaps

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, amcl, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am new to ROS and I'm just figuring things out. I just started with a project where I need to navigate/localize a robot in a non-static environment. I currently have an implementation of AMCL where the robot localizes itself using a static map made by gmapping.

However, the environment is non-static (there are objects that are placed in different locations at times) and also people walking around the robot. I want to start with a static map of the environment, an obstacle layer that marks/clears any new obstacles and a layer that checks for moving obstacles (people/other robots) and ignores these values. I would like AMCL to localize using the final costmap that these three layers form into.

I haven't used layered costmaps before and I am slightly unsure about how to begin. The tutorials on the wiki aren't as clear as other ROS resources on the web. Also, the tutorials talk about the compatibility of layered costmaps with ROS Hydro but I am working on ROS Indigo and would also like compatibility with Jade/Kinetic in the future.

Any help, suggestions or even a push in the right direction would be helpful. :)

-- Adi

(somewhat) related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/223524/is-it-possible-to-navigate-and-build-map-at-the-same-time/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246849/localization-with-layered-costmaps/) by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL localizes the robot over the static map. It does not use the costmaps or costmap layers to do so, those are part of the navigation nodes. It is not clear why do you want to do a localization at the same time that you changes your map. AMCL does quite a good job in localizing the robot even if the current environment does not perfectly match the static map.

If you really need it, I would use a SLAM algorithm to localize your robot in a map that changes, but even then, such algorithm would eliminate dynamic objects from the generated map.

You should have no problem working with Jade and Kinect regarding layered costmaps.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0